# Error on copy qmake.exe when building Qt

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt

I'm trying to build the Qt qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3 
following the instructions from http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/install-win.html. I've set the visual studio 2008 variables using vcvars32.bat.

But I'm getting errors like this when running configure command:

> Generating Code...
>               link  -OUT:qmake.exe project.obj main.obj makefile.obj unixmake.obj unixmake2.obj mingw_make.obj  option.obj winmakefile.obj projectgenerator.
>       obj property.obj meta.obj  makefiledeps.obj metamakefile.obj xmloutput.obj pbuilder_pbx.obj  borland_bmake.obj msvc_nmake.obj msvc_vcproj.obj msvc_vcx
>       proj.obj  msvc_objectmodel.obj msbuild_objectmodel.obj symmake.obj initprojectdeploy_symbian.obj  symmake_abld.obj symmake_sbsv2.obj symbiancommon.obj
>        registry.obj epocroot.obj qbitarray.obj  qbuffer.obj  qcryptographichash.obj  qfsfileengine.obj  qfsfileengine_iterator.obj  qbytearray.obj  qvsnprin
>       tf.obj  qbytearraymatcher.obj  qdatetime.obj  qdir.obj  qdiriterator.obj  qfile.obj  qtemporaryfile.obj  qabstractfileengine.obj  qfsfileengine_win.ob
>       j  qsystemlibrary.obj  qfsfileengine_iterator_win.obj  qfileinfo.obj  qglobal.obj  qhash.obj  qiodevice.obj  qlist.obj  qlinkedlist.obj  qlocale.obj
>       qmalloc.obj  qmap.obj  qregexp.obj  qtextcodec.obj  qutfcodec.obj  qstring.obj  qstringlist.obj  qtextstream.obj  qdatastream.obj  quuid.obj  qvector.
>       obj  qsettings.obj  qlibraryinfo.obj  qvariant.obj  qurl.obj  qsettings_win.obj  qmetatype.obj  qxmlstream.obj  qxmlutils.obj  qnumeric.obj ole32.lib
>       advapi32.lib qmake_pch.obj
>       Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
>       Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> copy qmake.exe G:\c++\qt\qt4.7\qt-src-4.7.3\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\bin\qmake.exe
>       The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> Creating makefiles in src...
>       Generating Visual Studio project files...
>
> execute: File or path is not found (G:\c++\qt\qt4.7\qt-src-4.7.3\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\bin\qmake)
>
> Qmake failed, return code -1
>
> Generating Makefiles...
>       execute: File or path is not found (G:\c++\qt\qt4.7\qt-src-4.7.3\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\bin\qmake)
>
> Qmake failed, return code -1

Seems like it fails on the copy command. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `copy` has trouble with pluses in the path. You should file a bug report at https://bugreports.qt.io, so that they properly escape paths in their build system.